# Connection pooling: interaction of MaxIdleConnsPerHost and IdleConnTimeout in http.Transport

Tags: go, connection-pooling

I am trying to write a heavy duty proxy to a set of web APIs in Golang. In order to prevent port exhaustion, I have decided to not use the `DefaultClient` and instead create a customized instance for `http.Client`. There are many interesting setting in the `http.Transport` that I can play around with.

I have come across the `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` and `IdleConnTimeout` fields and I have this question.

If I increase the value of `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` it means there will be more idle connection, but are they reusable idle connections? Or in other words, to make a decent connection pool, should I increase the value of `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` together with the timeout for `IdleConnTimeout` accordingly, or does it behave exactly the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

yes, IdleConns are reusable as these are ***keep-alive*** connections. But to make golang honour the reusability of keep-alive connections you need to make sure of 2 things in your applications.

1. Read until Response is complete (i.e. **ioutil.ReadAll(rep.Body)**)
2. Call **Body.Close()**

here's a [link](https://awmanoj.github.io/tech/2016/12/16/keep-alive-http-requests-in-golang/) for more explaination.